# How different is the lifestyle of male monks from that of the female monks?

Tags: monk, tibetan-buddhism, traditions, daily-life, monastery

Lifestyle means the daily activities carried out, the monasteries, the rules and regulations, etc.

If there are more than one types of the traditions, then please focus your answer on Tibetan Buddhism.

Comment: in the West, in Asia, or in both? Any of the for Tibetan traditions, or one of the four specifically?

Comment: _Asia_ specifically

Comment: Thank you. I shall work on answer and delete this very comment later (because it will no longer be relevant). Any of the four Tibetan traditions, or the four?

Comment: Would be nice, if you can answer about the four traditions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Bhikshuni Thubten Chodron founded Sravasti Abbey in 2003. It's based i the US, not Asia, but Venerable has her education and tradition from Asia (education India/tradition Tibet).  Male and female monastics train together there as equals—brothers and sisters supporting each other on the Dharma path.

They write a lot on their site about monastic life in general, see more: http://www.sravastiabbey.org/about/index.html

"Ordination in the Tibetan Buddhist Tradition" is an article from H.H. The Dalai Lama on both male/monks and female/nuns. http://www.dalailama.com/messages/buddhism/ordination-in-the-tibetan-tradition